# Why is this listview positioned above the previous <p>?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, overlap

I'm creating a page with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) and I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>You need to select a page:</p>

        <ol data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page2">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Item 2</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

It behaves as expected, except that on Chrome 10.0.648.205, I see the following:

[image]

Notice that the `<p>` is obscured by the list. Why is the list overlapping the text?

**Note:** you can play with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/r2whr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you could use the list divider instead of the p tag (Just theme it) like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/r2whr/4/

```
<div data-role="content">
   <!-- <p>You need to select a page:</p> -->

    <ol data-role="listview">
        <li data-role="list-divider">You need to select a page:</li> 
        <li><a href="#page2">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Item 2</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that adding elements inside of the list items (or between them) causes issues. Best to put all other tags or markup inside the li element itself

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, the listview's margin is defaulting to -15px all around. Just set the listview ol's margin to 0:

```
<ol data-role="listview" style="margin:0;">
    <li><a href="#page2">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">Item 2</a></li>
</ol>
```

(Or just set the top margin to 0 if you still want the -15px margin around the rest of the list.)

Comment: Could this possibly be a bug in jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a "bug".. Perhaps they did that for another reason that I'm not aware of. However, the jQuery CSS is setting it to -15px by default.

If you'd rather not tinker with the jQuery CSS, then just add an extra 1px margin to the bottom of your text. However, you'll then have to do this for whatever element you're putting on top of the listview.

If you're going to be using that listview/text layout in multiple places, consider making the change right in the jQuery CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

As BraedenP mentioned, the `listview`'s margin defaults to -15px on every side. I ran into this same issue, and found out that this is fully intentional:

> This is actually working as designed. Here's why: the body content block has 15px of padding so anything you drop in will look evenly spaced and that works well for everything except for these full-width lists.
>
> In most apps, you use a non-inset full width list alone with only toolbars and with no margins between them so we use the 15px margin to circumvent the body padding. If you're mixing and matching lists, buttons, form elements and content, the inset lists look better and that's what they are designed for.
>
> This system makes it very easy for people to use the same markup contentions and it "just works" for most cases. If you have a situation where you want a full-width list stacked with other items, you can add a CSS override as you suggested but it looks pretty odd unless you do some additional styling.

(From [a ticket at the jQuery github repo](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/902).)